# Why isnt this string to array working?

Tags: java

So an IPv4 string is passed to isValidElement

```
public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    String[] validString = token.split("\\."); 
    if (validString.length != 4)
        return false;
    for (String str: validString ) {
        try{                
            int i = Integer.parseInt(str); 
            if ((i < 0) || (i > 255)) { 
                return false; 
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

And thats all fine and dandy, but when that string is passed to a method to store the string into an array, it doenst work.

```
public void setParts(String ip) {
    parts = new int[4];
    if (!isValidElement(ip))
        for(int i = 0; i <= parts.length; i++)
            parts[i] = 0;
    else
        try {
            String[] ipArr = ip.split("\\.");
            for (int i = 0; i < ipArr.length; i++) {
                parts[i] = Integer.parseInt(ipArr[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            parts = new int[4];
        }
}
```

Where have I gone wrong/ what am I missing?

I have a JUnit Test

```
public void testSetPartsString() {
    correct1.setParts("12.14.16.18");
    int[] a = correct1.getParts();
    assertEquals(4, a.length);
    assertEquals(12, a[0]);
    assertEquals(14, a[1]);
    assertEquals(16, a[2]);
    assertEquals(18, a[3]);
```

But it stops working at

```
assertEquals(4, a.length);
```

Have I not reset the instance array parts properly?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE].

Comment: Why not set a break point and watch your code in debug mode?

Comment: @TimmyJim I put in breakpoints through setParts but its not working for me

Comment: Explain *exactly how* it "doesn't work"

Comment: The assertion error should tell you what the problem is

Comment: What does `getParts` do?

Comment: Since you seem to be dealing with IP addresses anyway, you should probably look into https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

Answer (score 0):

The following code works just fine.

```
public class AssertionCheck {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ip="12.14.16.18"; 
    int[] parts = new int[4];
           if(!(isValidElement(ip)))
               for(int i = 0; i<=parts.length; i++)
                   parts[i] = 0;
           else{
                   String[] ipArr = ip.split("\\.");
                   Assert.assertEquals(4, ipArr.length);
                   Assert.assertEquals(12, Integer.parseInt(ipArr[0]));
                   Assert.assertEquals(14, Integer.parseInt(ipArr[1]));
                   Assert.assertEquals(16, Integer.parseInt(ipArr[2]));
                   Assert.assertEquals(18, Integer.parseInt(ipArr[3]));
                   System.out.println("Assertion completed Successfully");
           }
           }

public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    String[] validString = token.split("\\."); 
    if (validString.length != 4)
        return false;
    for (String str: validString ) {
        try{                
            int i = Integer.parseInt(str); 
            if ((i < 0) || (i > 255)) { 
                return false; 
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

}